# How to save QR Scan details to listview using flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, sharedpreferences

I am currently building a QR Scanner App using flutter.  There I want to know how to scan a QR Code and save it permanently(using shared preferences) with the Details button.  Give me an example of this (there is no need to scan a Qr, there is only a simple text title and a description of how to save a circle avater).

[image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTetx.jpg)

Comment: Please provide some code of your App. Read more on [ask].

Comment: Do you want to save the QR code it self, or the result of scanning? if the latter, what is the type of this data? is it just a primitive type or is it an object?